# URL path appended rather than replaced

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, storyblok

I'd actually use some help with the dynamic routing when grouping pages in folder in storyblok.

For some reason, the name of the slug folder attaches to all the link that are currently in the header. So after clicking on a blog, the url changes to `localhost:3000/blogs/blog-name` and fetches the components of that page which is fine. But then everything gets the 'blogs' word before the url. So home page becomes  `localhost:3000/blogs/home` or about page becomes  `localhost:3000/blogs/about`

This is how I get the links:

```
<script setup>
const storyblokApi = useStoryblokApi();
const { data } = await storyblokApi.get("cdn/stories/config", {
  version: "draft",
  resolve_links: "url",
});
const headerMenu = ref(null);
headerMenu.value = data.story.content.header_menu;
</script>

<template>
  <header class="w-full h-24 bg-[#f7f6fd]">
    <div class="container h-full mx-auto flex items-center justify-between">
      <NuxtLink to="/">
        <h1 class="text-[#50b0ae] text-3xl font-bold">Storyblok Nuxt</h1>
      </NuxtLink>
      <nav v-if="headerMenu">
        <ul class="flex space-x-8 text-lg font-bold">
          <li v-for="blok in headerMenu" :key="blok._uid">
            <NuxtLink :to="blok.link.cached_url" class="hover:text-[#50b0ae]">
              {{ blok.link.story.name }}
            </NuxtLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

and this is the slug

```
<script setup>
const storyblokApi = useStoryblokApi();
const route = useRoute();
const slug = route.params.slug;
const story = await useStoryblok("blogs/" + slug, {
  version: "draft",
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <StoryblokComponent v-if="story" :blok="story.content" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you tried `useStoryblok("/blogs/"... `?

Comment: You mean without a slug? That didn't work

Comment: try putting `useStoryblok("blogs/" + slug + '.json',  {`.

Comment: With the slug but starting with a slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this `useStoryblok("/blogs/"...`, wit a slash at the beginning.